# How to fix face smooth after using Boolean modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I am new to Blender and am struggling to fix a problem with face smooth after I cut a hole through the object using the Boolean modifier.

The image shows the problem, and I tried using the triangulate shortcut, tried the edit normal modifier, tried subdivision modifier, but could not fix it.

Could anyone here help me with this?

[image]

Comment: I can' get what's gone wrong here, from that only picture, knowing the original solids involved in boolean operation would help. Did you try higher subdivisions on both objects before boolean, and a very low angle auto smooth on the resulting object?

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to Edit Mode
2. Select the vertices you want to smooth using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right click</kbd>
3. Select `Smooth Vertices` from the Tools menu

Comment: nonsense.......